# API Call exceeded in tSalesforceOutPut

Tags: api, limits, talend

I have a talend job with version 5.2. We imported the same job in talend version 6.2 to insert about 4000+ records.
In talend version 6.2 when I run the job API limit is getting exceeded as for every record API Limit is called.

i.e for 4000 records 4000 API are being called.

I am using talend 6.2 and Java 8. If this version is used we hit API limit as for every record API limit is called.

While in talend version 5.2 we dont hit above error.

In tSalesforceOutput component *Extend Insert* is set to true and commit level is set to 200.

Why I am hitting so much of API limit in v6.2?
Am i missing something?